# Need to update logic in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I have a stored procedure

```
with cte
as
( select   UserID,
            WorkHrs,
        case when left(ExtraHrs,1)='-' then -1 else 1 end as multiply,
           right(ExtraHrs,8) as timestring,
            --get hours in seconds:
            DATEPART(HOUR,right(ExtraHrs,8)) * 3600 AS h_in_s,
            --get minutes in seconds:
            DATEPART(MINUTE,right(ExtraHrs,8)) * 60 AS m_in_s,
           --get seconds:
            DATEPART(SECOND,right(ExtraHrs,8)) AS s,AtnDate,EmpName,EmpType,
           UserName, Role,StartDate,EndDate

  from      vw_Rept_Attend
)

select   UserID,dbo.udfTimeSpanFromSeconds(Sum(Left(workhrs,2) * 3600 + substring(Convert(varchar(8),workhrs), 4,2) * 60 + substring(Convert(varchar(8),workhrs), 7,2))) as WorkHrs ,
case when   sum((c.h_in_s + c.m_in_s + c.s) * multiply) < 0
            then '-' + CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(s,ABS(sum((c.h_in_s + c.m_in_s + c.s) * multiply)),0),114) 

            else CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(s,sum((c.h_in_s + c.m_in_s + c.s) * multiply),0),114)
        end as ExtraHrs ,EmpName,EmpType,UserName, Role,convert(VARCHAR(10),StartDate,105) as StartDate,convert(VARCHAR(10),EndDate,105) as EndDate

from    cte c  where  convert(date,AtnDate) between '2015-10-13' and '2015-10-14'   
group by UserID,EmpName,EmpType,UserName, Role,StartDate,EndDate
  Order by UserID
```

which I created some days ago using stack's help and this shows me result in SQL management studio as

[image]

This procedure sums extra hours of employee and it's working fine with time less than 24 hours, but with more than 24 hours it doesn't work.

I changed this using again stack's help to support greater than 24 hours to sum up as;

```
with cte
as
( select   UserID,
            WorkHrs,
        case when left(ExtraHrs,1)='-' then -1 else 1 end  as multiply,
           right(ExtraHrs,8) as timestring,
  (cast(substring(right(extrahrs, 8), 1, 2) as int) * 3600) + -- hours
  (cast(substring(right(extrahrs, 8), 4, 2) as int) * 60) + -- minutes
  (cast(substring(right(extrahrs, 8), 7, 2) as int))as secs,  -- seconds
          AtnDate,EmpName,EmpType,
           UserName, Role,StartDate,EndDate

  from      vw_Rept_Attend
)
select UserID,dbo.udfTimeSpanFromSeconds(Sum(Left(workhrs,2) * 3600 + substring(Convert(varchar(8),workhrs), 4,2) * 60 + substring(Convert(varchar(8),workhrs), 7,2))) as WorkHrs ,
case when sum((cte.secs) * multiply) < 0
            then '-' + CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(s,ABS(sum((cte.secs) * multiply)),0),114) 

            else CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(s,sum((cte.secs) * multiply),0),114)
        end  as WorkHrs,EmpName,EmpType,UserName, Role,convert(VARCHAR(10),StartDate,105) as StartDate,convert(VARCHAR(10),EndDate,105) as EndDate

from cte where convert(date,AtnDate) between '2015-10-13' and '2015-10-14'
group by UserID,EmpName,EmpType,UserName, Role,StartDate,EndDate,secs
  Order by UserID
```

and result of this is looking as:

[image]

here what I need the **First** result by using **Second** procedure,

I'm using SQL server 2008.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something unclear here. If first query returns expected results, why do you need to use second query?

Comment: as i mentioned that first query doesn't work if sum of  work hrs greater than 24 hours

Comment: Provide sample data, It will help to find solution.